# How can I install Guake (dropdown) terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-terminal

How to install this Guake Dropdown in my ubuntu machine? Is there any methods using apt-update or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you Try this?

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-guake-drop-down-terminal-terminal-on-ubuntu